# Set wallpaper from resource image file

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to set the background wallpaper from a resource image. I found and tried this code, but `FindResource()` can't find anything. Can anybody help me please?

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

std::cout << hInstance << std::endl;

HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), RT_BITMAP);

std::cout << hResInfo<< std::endl;

HGLOBAL hRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hResInfo);

std::cout << hRes << std::endl;

LPVOID memRes = LockResource(hResInfo);
DWORD sizeRes = SizeofResource(hInstance, hResInfo);

std::cout << memRes<< std::endl;
std::cout << sizeRes<< std::endl;

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\test.png", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD dwWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hFile, memRes, sizeRes, &dwWritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID) "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\test.png", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

> resource file

```
#include "resource.h"


IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "chrome.ico"


IDB_PNG1                PNG                     "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Pictures\\jano.png"
```

> resource.h

```
#define IDI_ICON1                       101
#define IDB_PNG1                        102
```

Comment: If `FindResource` can't find anything, this means your executable doesn't in fact have a resource attached to it with an ID of `IDB_PNG1` and type of `RT_BITMAP`

Comment: @jiw `BITMAP` is not a good resource type to use for a PNG image. BMP and PNG images are not the same thing. Try defining the resource to use `RCDATA` instead, and then use `RT_RCDATA` in the code.

Comment: RCDATA can't find either.

Comment: @jiw But, did you actually create the resource using `RCDATA`, or is it still using `BITMAP`? Can you please show your actual resource script that you are compiling into your executable? Have you tried looking at the executable with a resource viewer tool to see what resources are actually in it? Perhaps the ID of the resource is not using the *numeric* form of `IDB_PNG1` but is using the literal string `"IDB_PNG1"` instead? That is a common mistake. In your code, does using `"IDB_PNG1"` instead of `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1)` find the resource?

Comment: Ok, so I added the resource file.

Comment: I changed the PNG to RCDATA and it's working, the image was created, but i can't open the image..

Comment: @jiw If you want to use `PNG` for the resource type, that is fine, but you would have to specify the `PNG` type to `FindResource()`, not `BITMAP`. That is why it failed. `RCDATA` will also work. As for opening the file after extracting it, make sure `CreateFile()` and `WriteFile()` are successful and writes *all* of the bytes. The code you have shown has *zero* error handling in it.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau it wrote successfully as the file has same size, but it's not png/image anymore.

Comment: @jiw you are passing the wrong handle to `LockResource()`.  You need to pass in `hRes`, not `hResInfo`.  I have posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

- You are creating the `IDB_PNG1` resource as type `PNG`, but you are asking `FindResource()` to find a resource whose type is `BITMAP` instead.  The types need to match, so replace `RT_BITMAP` with `TEXT("PNG")` in the call to `FindResource()`.  Alternatively, use `RCDATA` instead of `PNG` in the `.rc` file, and then use `RT_RCDATA` instead of `RT_BITMAP`/`"PNG"` in the call to `FindResource()`.
- you are passing the wrong handle to `LockResource()`.  You are passing in `hResInfo` that is returned by `FindResource()`, but you need to instead pass in `hRes` that is returned by `LoadResource()`.

Answer (score -2):

[RCDATA resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/rcdata-resource#examples) stores integers or strings of characters And the data is returned by **LoadResource**.
With the statement: `IDR_PNG1 RCDATA {"pngwing.png"}`,
**LoadResource** returns **pngwing.png** while **LockResource** retrieves a pointer to the specified **resource** in memory.

Comment: `RCDATA` is for any arbitrary raw data.  The page you linked to even says so in its opening paragraph. But the rest of the page does not describe storing raw data from an external file, which is the most common use of `RCDATA`

Comment: I cannot agree more. I just ran OP's code.